# Mostrar imagen desde ruta almacenada con PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, sesiones

Verán, he ocupando la siguiente función para poder obtener los datos de mi sesión actual:

```
public function login(){
        $username = $this->input->post("username");
        $password = $this->input->post("password");
        $res = $this->Usuarios_model->login($username, sha1($password));

        if (!$res) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error","El usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectos");
            redirect(base_url());
        }
        else{
            $data  = array(
                'id' => $res->id_Usuarios,
                'username' => $res->username,
                'rol1' => $res->nombre,
                'rol' => $res->rol_id,
                'imagen_usr' => $res->imagen,
                'login' => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect(base_url()."index");
        }
    }
```

Y quise mostrar una imagen para el "perfil" de mi sistema.

La ruta en donde se encuentra está como campo en mi base de datos, y la imagen está en su respectiva carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siempre mostré los datos obtenidos de mi sesión actual de la siguiente forma:

```
<span class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $this->session->userdata("username")?></span>
```

Y lo que intenté hacer para mostrar la imagen fue:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>uploads/perfil/<?php echo $this->session->userdata("imagen_usr")?>" class="logo-lg" alt="User Image">
```

Pero no tuve éxito... Y también intenté de otras 3 formas, pero nada.

Comment: Qué contiene `$this->session->userdata("imagen_usr")` exactamente?

Comment: El valor del campo "imagen" de la tabla  "Usuario" (que sería la ruta que mencione, en este ejemplo: Montallas_Alfa.jpg)

Comment: Entonces lo que obtendrías es lo siguiente: `<img src class="img-circle">Montallas_Alfa.jpg` Esto no es lo que quieres obtener. Tendrás que ponerlo dentro del `scr=""`

Comment: Disculpa, me perdí, me preguntas o mencionas? :)

Comment: Tienes mucha razón, Al final de mi pregunta dije que había probado otras 3 formas, lamentablemente me volví a equivocar (Ya sabes... la hora y la desesperación). Esto era la linea que debí haber colocado aquí: <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>uploads/perfil/<?php echo $this->session->userdata("imagen_usr")?>" class="logo-lg" alt="User Image">

Comment: Ya veo, y que devuelve esto en la página? Se te rellena bien el `src`? Puedes inspeccionarlo con el navegador para ver qué está generando.

Comment: Algo curioso paso, Probe <img src='<?php echo base_url() ?>uploads/perfil/<?php echo $this->session->userdata("imagen_usr")?>' class="img-circle">     Pero no me manda el dato del campo imagen, solo da esto:  <img src='http://localhost/proyecto/uploads/perfil/' class="img-circle">

Comment: Pues eso significa que `<?php echo $this->session->userdata("imagen_usr")?>` esta vacío. Comprueba que contenga datos porque actualmente está vacío. Por otro lado, tienes unos `;` de más si te fijas.

Comment: Lo del ";" no se por que lo puso, pero no me lo arrojo en el resultado, por otra parte estoy trabajando en las correcciones para tener mejor fundamento.... En 10 min edito con nuevos resultados.... Gracias y disculpa este inconveniente.

Comment: Listo. Resulta ser que cometí un error mas (para variar...) y si, el campo estaba vació... ya que: el usuario con el que accedí al sistema es "dante5" y el de las imágenes era "dante6" y hasta el "dante15". Eso me pasa por enumerarlos así.... Pero fuiste de gran ayuda... por favor: deja tu linea de código como respuesta y con gusto la marco como solución.

Comment: Me alegro @Dante

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias, mas que nada, la paciencia :D   Buen dia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que comentas en los comentarios, el campo esta vacío.

`<?php echo $this->session->userdata("imagen_usr")?>` esta vacío. Comprueba que contenga datos porque actualmente está vacío.